# Trouble installing GSL using MacPorts

Tags: haskell, macports, gsl

I'm having trouble install gsl-devel using MacPorts on my Mac OS 10.7.5 Machine.  I try:

```
sudo port install gsl-devel +universal
```

I'm issuing this command by following the [instructions](https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix/blob/354d599b56d7bfb2124eb6939d4d87e9efa3faed/INSTALL.md) to install the Haskell module `hmatrix`.

However, I get an error message on command line after a bunch of configuring and compiling, and when I look into the log file, I see:

```
:debug:install Executing proc-post-org.macports.install-install-0
:info:install /opt/local/share/info/dir: Operation not permitted
:info:install Command failed: install-info /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_tarballs_ports_math_gsl-devel/gsl-devel/work/destroot/opt/local/share/info/gsl-ref.info /opt/local/share/info/dir
:info:install Exit code: 1
```

Any idea what problem this is?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: are your ports updated? try running `sudo port selfupdate` first

Comment: Yeah I did, so they should be updated.

Comment: Looks like you've got a permission problem on /opt/local/share/info/dir; what happens if you run the install-info command manually?

Comment: Also, does installing other packages with MacPorts work?

Comment: try installing just `gsl` and see if that works, see neverpanics answer and my comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's probably a bug in the gsl-devel port and you should file it as such. The Portfile tries to call `install-info` on a file that might not even be available anymore at the point of the installation process at which it is being called.

Since MacPorts 2.2, MacPorts uses sandboxing to prevent build systems (and commands called from Portfiles) from touching files outside the locations where they should – that's probably why you see the `Operation not permitted` error.

Instead of the `gsl-devel` port, just install the `gsl` port. It provides the same files and is also newer.

Comment: Yes this is a bug I can confirm on my own mac, also `gsl-devel` is an old version and perhaps depreciated, I would suggest uninstalling `gsl-devel` and install `gsl` which should work bug free and is the latest version

Comment: Thanks!  This moves me one step closer to actually getting `hmatrix` to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

try using brew to install the deps

Comment: Well, I'd prefer port because that probably would help me with the hmatrix installation, but I tried it anyway and got 
    `/usr/bin/install_name_tool: object: /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.15/lib/libgslcblas.0.dylib malformed object (unknown load command 11)` and 
    `/usr/bin/install_name_tool: object: /usr/local/Cellar/gsl/1.15/lib/libgsl.0.dylib malformed object (unknown load command 11)`